# How can I use components with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have this peace of code:

```
<item ng-repeat="name in names"></item>
```

And in `item.html`, there is bunch of things like `name.first`, `name.family` etc.
So, the problem is, I can't access `name` object because of the scope thing.

And I'm confused. shouldn't the component inheritance `name` at least?

this is my component:

```
app.component('item', {
   templateUrl: '/views/item.html'
});
```

Comment: Is there a variable `$scope.name` in the controller for this HTML page?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `item.html` itself has no controller. but its parent, 'items.html' has a controller that set `names' to an array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/iyNFJRv3MdyyVxzhJV4m):

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <item data="name" ng-repeat="name in names"></item>
  </body>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{family: "asdf", first: "test"}, {family: "qwerty", first: "test2"}]
});

angular.module('plunker').component('item', {
   templateUrl: 'item.html',
   bindings: {
     data: '='
   }
});
```

**item.html**

```
{{$ctrl.data.first}}
{{$ctrl.data.family}}
<br>
```

Basically what you have to do is use bindings to bind the data you are looping with ng-repeat to access it within your component.

Comment: Huh, interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `name` to the component.

Example from [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

```
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  controller: HeroDetailController,
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
```